# What is Mycoplasma Lyo medium?

Tags: microbiology, mycoplasma

Used for instance in this [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8219924)

> The role of genital mycoplasmas as pathogens - - are
>   generally neglected by diagnostic laboratories in the United Kingdom,
>   possibly due to the lack of a suitable commercially-available culture
>   medium. We have evaluated the bioMerieux Mycoplasma-Lyo system using
>   qualitative and quantitative studies and have found it to have
>   suitable qualities and practical advantages for detection of
>   Ureaplasma urealyticum and Mycoplasma hominis.

**What is Mycoplasma Lyo medium?**

I think it is some sort of anaerobic solid medium for all other mycoplasmas except M. pneumoniae (strict aerobe).

Comment: i think your guess is right as lyo means a solution [ref:lyophobic-meaning feared of other solution] and more over the site also has column to comment in where you can comment your question and you might get your direct answer over there

Comment: Lyo could just mean the medium is lysopholized. I've checked the company that makes this stuff and not found an answer yet

Comment: @rhill45 Did you mean "lyophilised" as in freeze-dried? I don't know of "lysophilised" as a term.